# Sort on (before or after today) in NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, sorting, datetime, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` that feeds a `UITableViewController` with `Appointment` entities that have, among others, a property `dateTime`.

My goal is to have a list of appointments sorted like this:

1. Today
2. Tomorrow
3. Day after tomorrow
4. Yesterday
5. Day before yesterday

In other words: 
First sort on whether it's before or after today, then on `dateTime`. So first sort on `(dateTime > %TODAY%)`, then on `dateTime` itself (future ascending, past descending).

Is there any way to do this? My problem is that I can't use %TODAY% in a sort descriptor, but maybe there's another way to achieve the same visual result.

**UPDATE**: Be aware the accepted answer is not possible with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I chose another solution, ordering the `Appointments` before showing the view., saving that to the database, and let the `NSFetchedResultsController` pick up the changes.

**UPDATE 2:**
Accepted answer did to do exactly what I wanted. My implementation:

```
let futureAppointments = appointments.filter({ $0.dateTime != nil && $0.dateTime?.compare(Date()) == .orderedDescending })
    .sorted(by: { $0.dateTime?.compare($1.dateTime! as Date) == .orderedAscending })

let pastAppointments = appointments.filter({ $0.dateTime != nil && $0.dateTime?.compare(Date()) == .orderedAscending })
    .sorted(by: {  $0.dateTime?.compare($1.dateTime! as Date) == .orderedDescending })

let sorted = futureAppointments + pastAppointments

for (index, appointment) in sorted.enumerated() {
    appointment.order = NSNumber(integerLiteral: index)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only idea. May be you can create **sortdescriptor** like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "test", ascending: true) { (v1, v2) -> ComparisonResult in
      guard let d1 = v1 as? Date else
      {
          return .orderedAscending
      }
      guard let d2 = v2 as? Date else
      {
        return .orderedAscending
      }
      if abs(d1.timeIntervalSinceNow) < abs(d2.timeIntervalSinceNow) { return .orderedAscending }
      if abs(d1.timeIntervalSinceNow) > abs(d2.timeIntervalSinceNow) { return .orderedDescending }
      return .orderedSame
}
```

I think it will be work.

Comment: You cannot use a block based sort descriptor in a fetchRequest. see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1

Comment: Like Jon said, I can't use that, but it made me think of another solution, ordering with your sort descriptor before the fetching. Now I have a property  `order` that is set every time somebody opens the view. It's never more than 10 or so appointments so, so I don't see any performance issues. Thanks

Comment: @Sergey FYI your answer did not do exactly what I wanted (I made the question more clear). I made my own implementation but if you want to, you are welcome to update your answer.

Comment: @Arjan Maybe I don't quite understand your implementation, but why do you filter and sort twice the result if it can be done in one sorted function? I think it will be more quickly.

Comment: @Sergey I can read and understand it in this way, but if you have a better one, please share :-) I need everything after now to be ascending, and  then everything before now to be descending.

Answer (score 1):

Use two fetchedResultsControllers, one sorted ascending with a predicate excluding ones created before today, and one sorted descending with a predicate excluding future appointments.

Write a function to convert between the fetchedResultsController indexPath and the tableview's indexPath and vice versa.  Just make sure to keep track of what the kind of indexPath you are dealing with and it is not that hard.

Comment: Hi Jon, I actually have a base class `CoreDataTableViewController` that I did not want to change or copy for one screen, so I went with another solution. Thanks for thinking along.